# source a config value with variables

Tags: scripts

Example:

I have a config file where I want below to have date in the value

`cat conf.ini`

```
path=/var/opt/[date]/yellow
```

I want my script `foo` to read path and substitute with date passed as argument to the script.

```
./foo.sh 08/20/2015
```

I want to substitute date in the path with the argument I provide in the script.

Answer (score 2):

Once the question has been changed and it was unclear what is meant, the **2nd part** of my answer is an answer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/656532/2) version of your question.

---

### But I will try it again

Using `awk`

```
#!/bin/bash
path=$(awk -F= '/path/ {gsub (/\[date\]/,"'"$1"'",$2); print $2}' conf.ini)
echo $path
```

*Example*

```
% cat conf.ini 
path=/var/opt/[date]/yellow

% ./foo 08/20/2016
/var/opt/08/20/2016/yellow
```

---

### 2nd part

Using `awk` in a script with the name `foo`, I don't like `eval` **;)**

```
#!/bin/bash
source conf
path=/var/opt/$(awk -F= '/^'"$1"'/ {print $2}' conf)/yellow
echo "$path"
```

---

Using `eval` **;)** in a script with the name `foo`

```
#!/bin/bash
source conf
eval path=/var/opt/'$'"$1"/yellow
echo "$path"
```

*Example*

```
$ cat conf
date=2015-08-04

$ ./foo date
/var/opt/2015-08-04/yellow
```

Comment: Yes for that question...you answer makes sense.

Comment: I have modified my question because my intent was different